# Is it a good practice to encapsulate the database access

Tags: database, language-agnostic, encapsulation

I developing an application.
I read somewhere that database should not be accessed directly but there should be kind of layer and via it database should be accessed.

I don't know the exact reason.

It will be great if you can provide me some reasoning or links to follow.

Comment: This should help you. This is a question which was previously posted which is similar to yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936172/how-to-encapsulate-database-access?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is really a good practice** to abstract/encapsulate your DB access logic from other part o. Data access layer should not be accessed directly or exposed to everyone. Meaning when you are designing an application, you must consider this important factor “Layered architecture” for example business layer, service layer, presentation layer and whatsoever.  The work flow like service layer (if its web application) calls business layer and business layer calls data access layer. All this layers should be very abstracted to each other or it should be accessible only to the very immediate layer (so called clients).

**Answer to your question:**  Let’s say your current data access implementation is based on plain JDBC/ODBC .After some time when your requirements grow;   you are planning to implement it with some ORM framework. In this case it’s really easy to switch/migrate between different data access logic written in different APIs without affecting rest of your application and still other layers are not aware of your changes since your design is very abstracted in nature.

**Bottom Line:**   Always work against abstracted interface rather against implementation.

Hope this is helpful and comments are appreciated